# API returning a bunch of \t and \n

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

what am I doing wrong here? i'm trying to consume the ncaa data but I'm getting a bunch of \t and \n in my data, which makes it so I can't serialize it to an object. Here is my function, you can literally run this as it takes no credentials to get the data.

```
public string GetGameInfo(DateTime dt)
{
    string content = string.Empty;
    string url = "http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/baseball/d1/2016/04/06/scoreboard.html";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resStream))
    {
        content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }


    return content;
}


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Ncaa
/// </summary>
namespace Ncaa
{

    public class callbackWrapper
    {
        public List<scoreboard> scoreboard { get; set; }
    }
    public class scoreboard
    {
        public DateTime day { get; set; }
        public List<games> games { get; set; }
    }

    public class games
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string conference { get; set; }
        public string gameState { get; set; }
        public string startDate { get; set; }
        public string startDateDisplay { get; set; }
        public string startTime { get; set; }
        public string startTimeEpoch { get; set; }
        public string currentPeriod { get; set; }
        public string finalMessage { get; set; }
        public string gameStatus { get; set; }
        public string periodStatus { get; set; }
        public string downToGo { get; set; }
        public string timeclock { get; set; }
        public string network_logo { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string contestName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string highlightsUrl { get; set; }
        public string liveAudioUrl { get; set; }
        public string gameCenterUrl { get; set; }
        //public ChampInfo champInfo { get; set; }
        //public IList<object> videos { get; set; }
        public home home { get; set; }
        public away away { get; set; }
    }

    public class home
    {
        public string teamRank { get; set; }
        public IList<int> RHEBreakdown { get; set; }
        public string iconURL { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string nameRaw { get; set; }
        public string nameSeo { get; set; }
        public string shortname { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        //public Social social { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string currentScore { get; set; }
        public IList<string> scoreBreakdown { get; set; }
        public string winner { get; set; }
    }

    public class away
    {
        public string teamRank { get; set; }
        public IList<int> RHEBreakdown { get; set; }
        public string iconURL { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string nameRaw { get; set; }
        public string nameSeo { get; set; }
        public string shortname { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        //public Social social { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string currentScore { get; set; }
        public IList<string> scoreBreakdown { get; set; }
        public string winner { get; set; }
    }

}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var json = GetGameInfo(DateTime.Now);

    //this one doesn't work
    //JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ncaa.callbackWrapper>(json);

    //I tried removing the /ts and ns with  no luck too
    json = json.Replace("\t", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);

    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ncaa.callbackWrapper>(json);


}
```

Comment: Hover over your "API" tag and read the description....

Comment: What's the callbackWrapper enclosing the JSON? Are you handling that already?

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with the `\t` and `\n`, if you really can't handle it, just use [`String.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) in C# before trying to parse the text.

Comment: What exactly do you mean why you say you've had `"no luck too"`.  Do you get an error message?  Does it thrown an exception?  Does it fail to compile? Does it run incorrectly?

Comment: The URL you're calling is expecting to be consumed directly in javascript through it's jsonp callback.  Do they provide an alternative raw json API?  If not, you'll have to strip the function name and parentheses off the start and end of your string before deserialising.

Comment: You got me to the right direction ManoDestra

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to answer why there's bunch of `\t`s and `\n`s in the response is because they ARE in your file. Those are respectively the tab character and the new line character.

I am not sure how you parse this , but most parsers should be able to handle this. In case you wrote your own, please post that code.

If the data returned will always be of format `callback(JSON)` you could strip the function call and simply parse the JSON using [NewtonsoftJSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

**EDIT:** After reviewing the added code, I can notice that you are not stripping the function call. You should remove that and try again ( e.g. try removing everything until the first ocurrence of the `{` character and after last, or any other way you like )

Comment: I updated my post to have my classes and parsing code, can you see anything I'm missing then?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I did get it working. Doing this to the json helped.

```
json = json.Replace("callbackWrapper(", string.Empty).Replace(");", string.Empty);
```

Then, just parsing it as a scoreboard object, instead of a callback wrapper object.

Comment: Note that this may be unsafe, since if the actuall content contains either `);` or `callbackWrapper(`, it will also be replaced. While this is highly unlikely, it should still be avoided.